# Directory.Delete - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net

The files exist and I have access to delete them on my Domain authorized Windows account, from which I am compiling and running the program.  I've always assumed that the program will use that account when performing actions on network drives.  Is this not the case?

I have tried to runAs the .exe in windows with an account that has full access to the folder and files and the same error is displayed.  Should this be working or do I need to do something in the code to allow the program to run certain actions as a certain user?

At the moment, I'm not running the code in a separate thread or background worker.  I've simply created a method that performs the following:

```
Directory.Delete(NetworkDirectory, true);
Directory.Delete(NetworkDirectoryTwo, true);
```

Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to access files/directories across the network, you need to have the appropriate permissions set on the network share, not just the permissions set on the actual folder. So your account may have full access to `C:\MyData\*`, but if it's shared as `\\mycomputer\MyData` and the folder is shared as read-only, you would get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: The account that I am using is a domain administrator account that has full access to both the share and the drive.

Comment: @user So you can successfully browse to `\\mycomputer\MyData` and delete the folder there through Windows Explorer? AFAIK, your program should by default use the credentials of the user who launches it to access network resources.

Comment: I thought so too.  Something odd is happening.  Is there an alternative method of deleting a folder and all of it's files and sub-folders.  I'm trying to figure out how to do so recursively and having a bit of trouble coming up with something that works.